# Firebase Jest auth/network-request-failed' error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs

I'm trying to do Firebase testing Using Jest. This is my test case.

```
test('Test Firebase Connection', done => {
    let history = [];
    function callback(history) {
        expect(history[0]).toBe('/dashboard');
        done();
    }
    firebaseDAO.init('myEmail', 'mypassword', history);
    setTimeout(callback, 4000,history);
});

export const init = (username, passwordPassed, history) => {
    let historyData = history;
    const email = username;
    const password = passwordPassed;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    promise.catch(e => console.log(e));
    promise.then(() => {historyData.push('/dashboard');});
};
```

When I run the test with `Idea-Webstorm-Jest` Plugin it Works. (Test passes.)
But when I try with `npm Test` command. Firebase gives me following Error.

> {code: 'auth/network-request-failed',
>           message: 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.' }

So why it is fails when `npm Test` command runs? Anyone can help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: yes I changed the"test" in "scripts" in package.json  as bellow. 
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "CI=true react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }

and tried npm test it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too, i looked for google and i found that my input or button in html was in type:"submit" which made the page refresh, it's better to do type"button"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31405661)